# Reading the SAML response from third party server in Angular 7 project

Tags: angular, angular7, saml-2.0

I have created one **angular 7** project

```
http://myproject.com/
```

If the user is not logged in the i redirect the user to another secure auth server`(https://secureauth.com)` to login.Here it promted to enther username and password.Then it checks the user credentials.

once the user successfully logged in to the secure auth server. it returns the one SAML response. For that i have enabled the return URL as

```
http://myproject.com/
```

in secure auth server. Here i need to process the SAML response from my angular project.

I have some doubts,

How can i process the SAML response in angular 7 ?
Since it is a client side language. Is it possible to get the response ?

Please share some ideas about this .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question 1**: Here i need to process the SAML response from my angular project.
How can i process the SAML response in angular 7?

**Answer**:
You need to implement SAML SP with your Angular 7 web application to process the SAML response sent by your SAML IdP (such as Shibboleth IdP).

[SAML2.0 WebSSO with angular client](https://github.com/slem1/saml-angular) at GitHub repository is the open-source client Angular app released in March 2018.

For quick deployment of SAML SP on your production environment, leveraging third-party SAML SP (such as SAML2.0 WebSSO with angular client) is highly recommended. Then you have sufficient time to develop your own SAML SP for your Angular 7 web application.

**Question 2**:Since it is a client side language. Is it possible to get the response?

**Answer**:
Yes. It is possible for Angular 7 app to get the response, decode the SAML response, validate SAML assertion signature, and then retrieve the user info from the SAML response to log in to your Angular 7 app 
if you implement SAML SP with your Angular 7 app and map SAML user with local user account of your Angular 7 app.

**SAML SP in your Angular 7 project** is responsible for **Reading the SAML response from third party SAML IdP server** (such as "https://secureauth.com").

(I) [How to build and run Shibboleth SAML IdP and SP using Docker container](https://github.com/winstonhong/Shibboleth-SAML-IdP-and-SP) at GitHub repository provides the instruction on building a SAML-based Authentication/Authorization Provider using Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP.

- Shibboleth SAML IdP is responsible for identity federation.
- OpenLDAP is responsible for identity authentication.

This will help you to gain hands-on experience on **how SAML SP processes the SAML response sent by the third-party SAML IdP**.

(II) I have validated SAML Single Sign-On (SSO) provided by Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP (Identity Provider) and OpenLDAP for the following enterprise applications. In other words, I leveraged Docker-running Shibboleth SAML IdP and OpenLDAP to log in to the following enterprise applications successfully.

```
Microsoft Office 365
Google G Suite
Salesforce
Dropbox
Box
Amazon AWS
OpenStack
Citrix NetScaler
VMware vCloud Director
Oracle NetSuite
```

(III) Another StackOverflow question ["How to implement or integrate single sign on with SAML and Shibboleth"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422985/how-to-implement-or-integrate-single-sign-on-with-saml-and-shibboleth) provides valuable information and discussions on SAML configuration.