# Spartacus SAML Single Sign On for ASM Implementation Reference

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Currently our customer is using JSP based accelerator storefront. ASM module is having SAML based SSO for employees using Microsoft Azure AD as IDP. JSP storefront have AssistedStorefrontFilter to manage SAML message and create ASM user session.

Do we have something OOT available with Spartacus storefront so that ASM can have SAML based SSO integration?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: @OP have you been able to achieve this flow ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spartacus doesn't support SAML OOTB. Take a look at the docs on session management (`angular-oauth2-oidc` is used):
https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/

If you want to implement SAML based SSO you need to alter default session management logic to fit SAML flow. Some examples can be found on stackoverflow as well:
[Reading the SAML response from third party server in Angular 7 project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56678472/reading-the-saml-response-from-third-party-server-in-angular-7-project)