# How enable SSO（SAML or OpenID）for spartacus

Tags: openid, saml, spartacus-storefront

Recently we are trying to enable SSO login for spartacus(on CCV2). Would you have any guidance on this.

Comment: Hi @Edward
Please see following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66547053/13845333
Also you can find more information about OpenId in Spartacus docs: https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/session-management/#configuring-openid